# How to convert DataRow[] to List<string[]>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have

```
DataTable dt;
DataRow[] drArray = dt.Select().ToArray();
```

My requirement  is i want to convert `drArray` as `List<string[]>`
or
Converting Datatable to `List<string[]>` in a fastest way.

Comment: instead of using `ToArray()`, use `ToList()` ?

Comment: It makes no sense to convert a DataTable to a String array.  What output would you expect?

Comment: ToList() is returning List<System.Data.DataRow> instead i want to convert this as List<string[])

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this will get you what you want:

```
List<string[]> results =
    dt.Select()
        .Select(dr =>
            dr.ItemArray
                .Select(x => x.ToString())
                .ToArray())
        .ToList();
```

This only works if the items stored in `dr.ItemArray` have overriden `.ToString()` in a meaningful way. Luckily the primitive types do.

Comment: I tried to convert the code to a vb.net but I can't get it

Comment: @Esraa_92 - `Dim results As List(Of String()) = dt.Select().Select(Function(dr) dr.ItemArray.Select(Function(x) x.ToString()).ToArray()).ToList()`